# Xml serialization as elements with properties

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I generally use the DataSet.GetXml() method to serialize datasets, and I came across a problem: Is there an easy way to serialize a dataset object using properties rather than elements? For example, the GetXml() method might generate this from a data set:

```
<foo>
<height>bleem</height>
<color>yurple</color>
</foo>
```

but, I would like to see something like:

```
<foo height="bleem" color="yurple" />
```

I realize there are constraints on the property oriented approach, but I am using database data, so uniqueness shouldn't be an issue. I have been digging around SO, but I cannot find anything covering this. Any XML experts out there have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no XML expert--I just play one on TV.

I would use the [DataColumn.ColumnMapping Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.columnmapping%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to determine how your columns are mapped.  For all the columns you want mapped as XML attributes, set their `ColumnMapping` equal to `MappingType.Attribute`.

Comment: @MadTigger Glad I could help. If this answer solved your problem please mark it as the **accepted answer**.  Doing so will let others who come across this question know a solution was found. Plus, it'll give me some more of that sweet, sweet rep.